# Ghost Drillbit (One or more drillbits in cluster have different version: Undefined.)

Tags: kubernetes, apache-zookeeper, apache-drill

I have a kubernetes stack with some drills and zookeeper installed.

- 3 drillbits
- 1 zookeeper
- The drillbits are visible to each other
- The zookeeper is visible from each drill container

However, whenever I navigate to any drillbit:8047 I see this one extra "ghost" drillbit:

*(screenshot of debug configuration 1 drill : 1 zookeeper)*
[image: Dril does not support clusters containing a mix of drillbit versions. Current drillbit version is xxx. One r more drillbits in cluster have different versions: Undefined]

- In this case, no query works - all will silently fail with no error and there is no profile to be found after
- zookeeper log is full of these errors:

  > WARN [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@349] - caught end of stream exception
  > EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x0, likely client has closed socket

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I found out that the `drill-override.conf` was misconfigured.

This error was caused by empty `cluster-id` in my configuration:

```bash
drill.exec: {
  cluster-id: "",
  zk.connect: "my-zookeeper-host:2181",
  ...
```

That's because I used an env propagation of variables:

```bash
drill.exec: {
  cluster-id: "${DRILL_CLUSTER_NAME}",
  zk.connect: "${ZOOKEEPER_HOST}:${ZOOKEEPER_PORT}",
  ...
  ---

  envsubst < core-site.xml.template > ./conf/core-site.xml
```

...and I had a typo in the `$DRILL_CLUSTER_NAME` variable.

---

It took me 3 days to find it. Three bloody days. Would be nice if drill threw some exception in this case or whatever?

---

Well, maybe this will save someone three days of his life...